# JS Fetch - data is undefined - promise

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I want to analyse anwser from http request, display error if needed then return data.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
fetch(URL,{method:"GET"})
.then(async response => { await read_errors(response) })
// .then(response => { read_errors(response) }) (Both had been tried)
.then( function(data) { 
    doSomething(data)
})
.catch( error => { display_error(error) })
```

With this function :

```
async function read_errors(response) {
    const isJson = response.headers.get('content-type')?.includes('application/json');
    const data = isJson ? await response.json() : null;

    const isText = response.headers.get('content-type')?.includes('text/');
    const text = isText ? await response.text() : null;

    // check for error response
    if (!response.ok) {
        // get error message from body or default to response status
        const error = (data && data.message) || text || response.status;
        console.error("Something went wrong : ",error)
        return Promise.reject(error);
    } else {
        fckng_response = isJson ? data : text
        return Promise.resolve(fckng_response)
    }
}
```

But I've got `TypeError: data is undefined`

The answer from server is all right with headers and data OK.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you taken some debugging steps to narrow down the problem? For example at which point in your code is `data` undefined? In the `read_errors` function, or in the `fetch` part (`doSomething(data)`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning the result of calling `read_errors` in the `.then` callback. Either add a return statement or remove the braces (`{}`).

```js
.then(response => read_errors(response))
// no need for async here
```

It is simpler to completely work with async and await, without mixing it with callbacks.

```js
try {
    const response = await fetch(URL);
    const data = await read_errors(response);
    doSomething(data);
} catch (error) {
    display_error(error);
}
```

Comment: OK thanks a lot ! It's working. I honnesly don't know why I've added braces.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you need to return the data from the read_errors() function. Here's the modified code:

```
fetch(URL, { method: "GET" })
  .then(response => read_errors(response))
  .then(data => {
    doSomething(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    display_error(error);
  });

async function read_errors(response) {
  const isJson = response.headers.get('content-type')?.includes('application/json');
  const data = isJson ? await response.json() : null;

  const isText = response.headers.get('content-type')?.includes('text/');
  const text = isText ? await response.text() : null;

  if (!response.ok) {
    const error = (data && data.message) || text || response.status;
    console.error("Something went wrong:", error);
    throw error; // Use throw instead of Promise.reject
  } else {
    const fckng_response = isJson ? data : text;
    return fckng_response;
  }
}
```